# como precisar la velocidad en km/h usando react-native-geolocation-service

Tags: typescript, react-native, geolocalización, gps

Estoy creando un velocímetro con react native donde quiero obtener la velocidad en km/h por medio del npm react-native-geolocation-service.

el cual me regresa el siguiente objeto:

```
{
"coords": {"accuracy": 20,  "altitude": 2219.3774509874866, "altitudeAccuracy": 1.053762674331665, "heading": 134.74325561523438, "latitude": 20.049, "longitude": -90.42396, 
   "speed": 0.12005957216024399
 }, "mocked": false, "provider": "fused", "timestamp":1668138841384
}
```

el speed viene en m/s para pasarlo a km/h simplemente multiplique el speed * 3.6,
pero cuando ejecuto la app sin moverme de repente salta a 5 km/h, y no logro hacer que ese dato sea mas preciso, hay alguna manera de lograrlo? que la velocidad en km/h sea lo mas precisa posible?

este es mi code:

```
const getLocation = () => {
    const result = requestLocationPermission();
    result.then(res => {
      console.log('res is:', res);
      if (res) {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            console.log(position);
            setLocation(position);
            setSpeed(position.coords.speed);
          },
          error => {
            // See error code charts below.
            console.log(error.code, error.message);
            setLocation(false);
          },
          {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1},
        );
      }
    });
    console.log(location);
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    getLocation();

    location;
    speed;
    let x = (speed * 3.6);
    setSpeedKmh(x);

   }, [location, speed])
```

Answer (score 1):

El GPS siempre va a tener un error de precisión, para corregirlo, mi solución fue obtener los datos mediante la distancia y no el tiempo. Descubrí que los celulares hacen micro saltos de ubicación y esto hace que nos retorne datos erróneos, así que utilicé el siguiente código

```
Location.watchPositionAsync({
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
          distanceInterval: 60
        }, (location) => {
            const { coords: { latitude, longitude, speed }, timestamp, } = location;

            const datetime = moment(timestamp);
            const formatDate = datetime.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
        
            const res = {
                latitude,
                longitude,
                formatDate,
                speed: Math.round(speed * 3.6),
                user_id: user.id,
            };
        });
```

Este código soluciono mi problema de precisión, cada vez que avanzo 60 metros este me retorna una respuesta aceptable, y evita que se detecten errores